# Is this a bug in Fuel SDK library?

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

While browsing the code I got from [Github](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp) (version .9), I noticed the code at line 425 in `ET_Client.cs` is very strange with the if-statement.  It seems to be wrong?

```
if (response != null)
    this.Code = (int)response.StatusCode;
{
   if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: It makes more sense for this line "this.Code = (int)response.StatusCode;" to be inside the brace right after the first if-statement.

Comment: Why not post an issue on the Github page? https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/issues

Answer (score 0):

I agree, I have submitted a pull request with a fix.

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-CSharp/pull/26